# Uploading pdf / docx files including images to server using retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit, uri, mediastore

I am new to android development. I came across with a tutorial which enables me to upload images to PHP server using retrofit. However I cannot figure out the way to upload other file types. I just need to get the absolute file path (files like PDF and DOCS) by modifying the code mentioned below. I want to use **MediaStore** as the option as my entire project has already been set up.

```
/*
    * This method is fetching the absolute path of the image file
    * if you want to upload other kind of files like .pdf, .docx
    * you need to make changes on this method only
    * Rest part will be the same
    * */
    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: "I just need to get the absolute file path (files like pdf and docs) by modifying the code mentioned below" -- that will not work on Android 10 and above, and it was never reliable. You will not be able to get the "absolute file path" for most content. Use the `Uri` with `ContentResolver`, such as [the `InputStreamRequestBody` shown in this OkHttp issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196).

Answer (score 0):

use multipart feature of retrofit. refer this tutorial in case you are new to android retrofit [multiparttutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) remember if you will going to have uploading and downloading operation then you must should have separate directory of different file which helps you to manage it.

Comment: The tutorial is very helpful. However, in this case I am just looking for a quick fix to the code that I have mentioned. I am only able to select and get the path of image files. I just want to edit the code in a way that I can do the same will all types of files. If you can please help me edit the code mentioned.